# changing the value of variable in thread while its running

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, tcp

I am building an android app in which service is running and it has a thread which listens for tcp connections and receive the message and respond back.Actually what I want to do is to give the user the choice to respond with yes or no ,when the thread will accept the connection, My service class is this:

```
public class Receiver extends Service {
    static String TCP_RECEIVE = "soft.b.peopleassist";
    public static String ip;
    DatagramSocket socket;
     private WifiManager.WifiLock wifiLock=null;
     private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock=null;
volatile public static String outgoingMsg="null";
    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")


    public String getIpAddr() {
           WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
           WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
           int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();

           String ipString = String.format(
           "%d.%d.%d.%d",
           (ip & 0xff),
           (ip >> 8 & 0xff),
           (ip >> 16 & 0xff),
           (ip >> 24 & 0xff));

           return ipString;
        }



    private void listenAndWaitAndThrowIntent(Integer port) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket ss = null;
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(port);
            //ss.setSoTimeout(10000);
            //accept connections
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
            //receive a message




            String incomingMsg = in.readLine() + System.getProperty("line.separator");
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

            try {
                     jsonObj = new JSONObject(incomingMsg);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                String trans=(String) jsonObj.get("TranId");
                String ide=(String) jsonObj.get("Amount");
                String hashs=(String) jsonObj.get("Basket");
                incomingMsg=trans+","+ide+","+hashs;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i("TcpServer", "received: " + incomingMsg);


            //send a message
        //  String outgoingMsg = "goodbye from port " + port + System.getProperty("line.separator");
            // outgoingMsg = "ok"; 

            broadcastIntent(incomingMsg);
            incomingMsg=null;
                Thread.sleep(3000);

            out.write(outgoingMsg);
            out.flush();

            Log.i("TcpServer", "sent: " + outgoingMsg);

            broadcastIntent(incomingMsg);

            //SystemClock.sleep(5000);
            s.close();
            outgoingMsg="null";
        } catch (InterruptedIOException e) {
            //if timeout occurs
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (ss != null) {
                try {
                    ss.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }











    private void broadcastIntent(String message) {
    Intent  intent = new Intent(Receiver.TCP_RECEIVE);
        intent.putExtra("messages", message);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    Thread UDPBroadcastThread;

    void startListenForUDPBroadcast() {
        UDPBroadcastThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                //  InetAddress broadcastIP = InetAddress.getByName(ip); //172.16.238.42 //192.168.1.255
                    Integer port = 21111;
                    while (shouldRestartSocketListen) {
                        listenAndWaitAndThrowIntent(port);
                    }
                    //if (!shouldListenForUDPBroadcast) throw new ThreadDeath();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("UDP", "no longer listening for UDP broadcasts cause of error " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
        UDPBroadcastThread.start();
    }

    private Boolean shouldRestartSocketListen=true;

    void stopListen() {
        shouldRestartSocketListen = false;
        if(socket!=null)
        socket.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i("Service", "WiFi lOCK");

        WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiLock = wm.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL , "MyWifiLock");
        wifiLock.acquire();

        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Lock");
        wakeLock.acquire();
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopListen();
         wifiLock.release();
            wakeLock.release();

        Log.i("UDP", "Service stoped");
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

            shouldRestartSocketListen = true;

        startListenForUDPBroadcast();
        Log.i("TCP", "Service started");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

outGoingMsg is the message which is actually a response.Now I want the thread to wait until the value of this variable in thread is not changed.There is another class from where I want to change this variable.For now am calling sleep to sleep this thread for few seconds but its not the right way because if after few seconds user don't respond it will automatically send null..please help how can I do this..

Comment: Receive Message -> Store the connection -> Propagate the message to user -> Retrieve user response -> Get the stored connection -> Send response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put the waiting action into an loop, which breaks if the value is set.
for reasons of visibility you should use an volatile modifier.

I'll post an example in a minute.

```
volatile String valueIAmWaitingFor; // Class Variable
...

while(valueIAmWaitingFor == null){ 
     Thread.sleep(3000); 
}
//go on
```

The other method can now set valueIAmWaitingFor.

volatile:

> Declaring a volatile Java variable means:   The value of this variable
>   will never be cached thread-locally: all reads and writes will go
>   straight to "main memory";   Access to the variable acts as though it
>   is enclosed in a synchronized block, synchronized on itself.

This is just one way to do this. There are many more secure solutions (but also more complex than this hotfix)

EDIT: of course it has to be `valueIAmWaitingFor == null`, and not  `valueIAmWaitingFor != null`

Comment: its still sending null,I dont know y,

Comment: where/how are you setting the outgoingMsg?

Comment: Receiver.outgoingMsg="no";
because its static as well.so calling with the class name.

Comment: you should add some system.out on both threads. then you see when you are setting the value and when you are waiting for it.

Comment: i am not intiallizing outGoingMsg but at the end putting null to outGoingMsg ,,,and its working fine for the first time...

Comment: i dont understand. if you dont initialize it, it is null anyway. EDIT: well, in your code you DO initialize it with the String "null".